# python parsing: what file format uses `=>` OR how to read custom input files to dict

Tags: python, regex, parsing, file-format, parsimonious

When using the zmdp solver from [here](https://github.com/trey0/zmdp) i came across a funky file format that I haven't seen before, it uses `=>` for assignment. I wasn't able to find out what format it was from the package documentation (it says it is a "policy" format, but it must be based on something more generic)

```
{
  policyType => "MaxPlanesLowerBound",
  numPlanes => 7,
  planes => [
    {
      action => 2,
      numEntries => 3,
      entries => [
        0, 18.7429,
        1, 18.7426,
        2, 21.743
      ]
    },
    ### more entries ###
    {
      action => 3,
      numEntries => 3,
      entries => [
        0, 20.8262,
        1, 20.8261,
        2, 20.8259
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I researched a lot on what would be a straightforward way to parse such files (in Python), and also read [this blog post](https://tomassetti.me/parsing-in-python/#tools) which has a huge variety of options for lexing and parsing (the tools that looked most promising for my example seemed to be [parsimonious](https://github.com/erikrose/parsimonious) and [parsy](https://github.com/python-parsy/parsy)).
However, whatever solutions I can think of just feels like I'm re-inventing the wheel, and lexing and parsing seems to be an overkill for what I'm trying to do.
I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13532700/tips-on-parsing-a-custom-file-format-python) stackoverflow question which coincidentally seems to also be related to a format that uses `=>`. However, being lazy and minimalistic when it comes to code, I don't like the regex solution too much. My gut feeling tells me that there must be a 3-4 line solution to write the input file to a python dict or similarly useful format. In particular, I suspect that this is already standard syntax of some format I just am not aware of (it's obviously not csv, json, yaml or xml)

The **question** therefore is: Is the above a standard file format, and if yes, what is it?
If not, how do I parse this file elegantly and compactly in Python3, i.e. without regexing for every keyword?

Comment: Looking at the [source](https://github.com/trey0/zmdp/blob/55174941c85eb04ab2f6ea13d7f3fd72e8530d54/src/pomdpBounds/MaxPlanesLowerBound.cc#L544), especially the [parsing code](https://github.com/trey0/zmdp/blob/55174941c85eb04ab2f6ea13d7f3fd72e8530d54/src/pomdpBounds/MaxPlanesLowerBound.cc#L598), it looks very ad hoc and not the "JSON with =>" you might guess from looking at it. (Also, the code writes a big JSON-incompatible comment section at the top that you probably stripped out.)

Comment: You can probably *read* the format by stripping out the header, replacing `=>` with `:`, and stuffing the result into a JSON parser, but *writing* the format by dumping JSON and replacing `:` with `=>` won't work.

Comment: (Also, unquoted keys are not standard JSON, and Python's `json` module doesn't accept them.)

Comment: @user2357112 true about the unquoted keys. In terms of writing, at the moment i don't have that requirement but it's a good point.

Comment: for stripping out the comment section, i used `policy_str = re.sub(r"[#].*\n?", "", policy_str)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t see any differences from json here aside from replacing ‘=>’ with ‘:’ and adding a top level key.

```
filestr.replace(‘=>’, ‘:’)
dictionary = json.loads(filestr)
```

Edited after seeing comment above.

Unquoted keys are indeed not part of the json standard. To address that, you can use a library as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34812821/6809571) or you can regex it.

Comment: Exactly what i meant by elegant and compact! Great, thank you!

Comment: it actually required a little more work as pointed out by @user2357112: I had to add quotation marks around the keys, so I ended up using
`re.sub(r"\S+ =>", lambda m: "\"" + m.group(0).replace(" =>", "\":"), policy_str)` followedy by json.loads(policy_str)`

Comment: but overall still pretty compact and less work than writing an entire parser.